# NGINX Redirect Loop for a single page

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have an NGINX Webserver and I am trying to redirect the page 

    `www.example.com/newsletter` 

to 

    `www.example.com/blog/category/newsletter`

but the redirect rule I have is matching both locations and causing a redirect loop. How can I make the rule ignore the /blog/category page while still redirecting the /newsletter page?

The redirect rule that I am using is:
`rewrite ^/newsletter$ https://www.example.com/blog/category/newsletter permanent;`

I am not very good at regex and I am not even sure that is what I need to use to get the final page excluded from the redirect loop.

Comment: This cannot be the only problem. Can you please provide the entire server block? I'll debug your nginx config the moment I have it. The rewrite rule conflicts with something, but not with just itself.

Comment: You may need to add some context like the Location section. Does replacing `permanent` with `permanent break` at the end of the rewrite solve the problem?

Comment: This `rewrite` directive certainly matches nothing else than `/newsleter`. You should flush all caches that might apply here (including your browser). If you tested other expressions before, the redirect response might still be cached (because it is `permanent`). You can also try `curl -v` to check the actual response of the server.

Comment: I did clear the caches, for some reason it was matching the /newsletter in both and causing the redirect loop. Using the location block solution below fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't handle it with a rewrite, try this instead

```
location = /newsletter {
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/blog/category/newsletter;
}
```

Comment: Using the location block works. I was wondering though, why would you prefer to handle it with a location block? Is using that better than just having the rewrite outside a location block?

Comment: The point wasn't the location block, it's avoiding the rewrite, nginx does a return faster than a rewrite, so in terms of performance doing this is better than running the rewrite engine

[Check this link, it's very useful](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites)